# ошибка 0x80072F06 outlook (Exchange 2019)

Tags: windows, active-directory, exchange

почтовый сервер Exchange 2019

[image: 0x80072F06]

ошибка 0x80072F06, не загружает адресную книгу

что делать и где капать?

в инете нашел совет удалить все из папки \Exchange Server\ClientAccess\OAB
но это не помогло

Comment: дело было в сертификатах как только я его обновил сразу получилось все

Comment: В каких именно сертификатах? .
.
.